# change icon of a List with a Click with CSS

Tags: html, css, list, target

i have a NavList for my tabmenu like this:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#1"><span></span></a></li>
  <li><a href="#2"><span></span></a></li>
  <li><a href="#3"><span></span></a></li>
  <li><a href="#4"><span></span></a></li>
</ul>
```

Now in the css i take a background-img to the empty span, to have an icon in my menu. How can i change the icon when i click on the link?

a:active is only for the click. I need something like a:target. Is this possible?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I don't really understand what you want. Could you clarify your question a bit more? Besides `a:active` there is also `a:focus`. Maybe this helps you..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There currently is no way to 'permanently' mark certain elements as active/give them a specific class using pure CSS.

An option to do this would be using Javascript/jQuery as follows:

```
<ul class="tab-menu">
  <li><a href="#1"><span></span></a></li>
  <li><a href="#2"><span></span></a></li>
  <li><a href="#3"><span></span></a></li>
  <li><a href="#4"><span></span></a></li>
</ul>

<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        $('ul.tab-menu li').click(e){
            $('ul.tab-menu li').removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: with this jquery i add a class active to the li which i click or? Looks very nice :)

Comment: Yes, it basically adds the `.active` class to the one element that was clicked. You can then simply style the class using CSS.

Answer (score 2):

The only thing you can do using pure CSS would be :

```
a:target{
    color:red;
    outline:0;
}
```

With the following html

```
<ul>
  <li><a id="1" href="#1"><span></span>Link 1</a></li>
  <li><a id="2" href="#2"><span></span>Link 2</a></li>
  <li><a id="3" href="#3"><span></span>Link 3</a></li>
  <li><a id="4" href="#4"><span></span>Link 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

**Demo**

http://jsfiddle.net/g3nfu1ry/

To change your icon instead of the color of the link, put the id on the span and change the css to `span:target` and modify to your needs

If you need a solution where you don't have the same id on the link as the target, you will need to use javascript I think.

Answer (score 0):

i don't now is it possible or not but you can use many other pseudo class of `a` tag like `a:hover`, `a:visited` etc..